Can I know which is the correct command to upload the file to the Ubuntu server?
I am trying to upload the file using the terminal to the Ubuntu python3 virtual environment but I am below two getting error.
1. If I am not logged in using the terminal and trying to upload a file

    xyz@xyzs-MacBook-Air / % scp -r /Users/xyz/Downloads/model/api.py root@myserverip:/home/ubuntu/virtualweb
    root@myserverip: Permission denied (publickey).
    scp: Connection closed

2. I have logged in in ubuntu using host details

  ubuntu@ip:~$ scp -r /Users/xyz/Downloads/model/api.py root@ip:/home/ubuntu/virtualweb
  scp: stat local "/Users/xyz/Downloads/model/api.py": No such file or directory
  ubuntu@ip:~$

Can I know which is the correct command to upload the file to the Ubuntu server?

Do you want to copy files over ssh?

@ArchismanPanigrahi, the files are in my Macbook and I have to upload them to the Ubuntu ec2 server. i have a virtual environment. and I have to upload it

What happens if you use ubuntu@myserverip instead of root@myserverip? Edit your question and add the information.

@user68186, I am getting the same error if I try ubuntu
